# Flexbox wont expand

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Working with a flexsite project and trying to make a flex element to expand when more "content" is added than the current height.

At the moment a scrollbar is added. But I want it to expand. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rhax00e3/)

```css
html,
body,
.r_flex_container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.r_flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  background-color: blue;
}

.r_flex_fixed_child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.r_flex_expand_child {
  flex: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_flex_container">
  <div class="r_flex_fixed_child">
    <p> This is the fixed child of the flex container </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">

  </div>
  <div class="r_flex_expand_child">
    <article>an article blah blah blah an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf
      asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf
      asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article
      blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah
      blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah
      asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf
      asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf
      asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf
      an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an
      article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an
      article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah
      asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="r_flex_fixed_child">
    this is the fixed footer child of the flex container asdfadsf
    <p> another line</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rhax00e3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `flex:auto` to `flex:1`

```css
html,
body,
.r_flex_container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.r_flex_container {
  background-color: blue;
}

.r_flex_fixed_child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.r_flex_expand_child {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_flex_container">
  <div class="r_flex_fixed_child">
    <p> This is the fixed child of the flex container </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">

  </div>
  <div class="r_flex_expand_child">
    <article>an article blah blah blah an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf
      asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf
      asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article
      blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah
      blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah
      asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf
      asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf
      asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf
      an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an
      article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an
      article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah
      asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="r_flex_fixed_child">
    this is the fixed footer child of the flex container asdfadsf
    <p> another line</p>
  </div>
```

**OP's comment**

> Meh, this makes the flex element not to fill the content if it's blank

you can set `height:100%` only in `html,body` and `min-height:100%` in `.r_flex_container` along with `flex: 1` (or `flex: auto`) in `.r_flex_expand_child`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body,
.r_flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.r_flex_container {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.r_flex_fixed_child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.r_flex_expand_child {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_flex_container">
  <div class="r_flex_fixed_child">
    <p> This is the fixed child of the flex container </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">

  </div>
  <div class="r_flex_expand_child">
    <article></article>
  </div>
  <div class="r_flex_fixed_child">
    this is the fixed footer child of the flex container asdfadsf
    <p> another line</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sweet, it's working perfect in the fiddle, but on my website, the content goes outside the element into the footer, any ideas? It's not expanding like it does on the fiddle.

Comment: remove `height:100%` from `html, body, .flex_container`

Comment: Meh, this makes the flex element not to fill the content if it's blank

Comment: The idea with the flex box was to fill empty content, if there was any, but still expand, if more content than the height was added.

Comment: I tried to add a min-height instead of height, but that only dubbles the height ( if the content is filled )

Comment: If the height is set to 100%, it fills the empty blank space of the browser

Comment: @Jack sorry for the wait, work stuff came up, I've updated the answer which is valid as the LGSon

Comment: Thanks bud, Working :)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you actually need to do is to remove `overflow: auto` from the `.r_flex_expand_child` rule.

That will work in most browsers but IE (see below for IE), and the reason it does, is that a flex item by default can't be smaller than its content, hence it will overflow with an outer scroll as result, though I find the `min-height` version below more correct.

Stack snippet

```css
html, body, .r_flex_container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.r_flex_container {
  background-color: blue;      
  /*display: flex;                 already set in first rule  */
  /*flex-flow: column nowrap;      already set in first rule, nowrap is default  */
}

.r_flex_fixed_child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.r_flex_expand_child {
  flex: auto;
  /*overflow: auto;                remove as it should not scroll  */
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_flex_container">
  <div class="r_flex_fixed_child">
    <p> This is the fixed child of the flex container </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">

  </div>
  <div class="r_flex_expand_child">
    <article>an article blah blah blah an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf
      asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf
      asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article
      blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah
      blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah
      asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf
      asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf
      asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf
      an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an
      article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an
      article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah
      asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="r_flex_fixed_child">
    this is the fixed footer child of the flex container asdfadsf
    <p> another line</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To make it work in IE, do these 2 things:

- Remove `height: 100%` from the `html, body, .r_flex_container { ... }` rule
- Add `min-height: 100vh` to `.r_flex_container { ... }` rule

The `min-height: 100vh` is needed for the `.r_flex_container` to fill the viewport, even if the elements are empty, and to allow it to grow when the content is bigger.

Stack snippet 2

```css
html, body, .r_flex_container {
  /*height: 100%;                  removed  */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.r_flex_container {
  min-height: 100vh;           /*  added  */
  background-color: blue;
  
  /*display: flex;                 already set in first rule  */
  /*flex-flow: column nowrap;      already set in first rule, nowrap is default  */
}

.r_flex_fixed_child {
  flex: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.r_flex_expand_child {
  flex: auto;
  /*overflow: auto;                remove as it should not scroll  */
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="r_flex_container">
  <div class="r_flex_fixed_child">
    <p> This is the fixed child of the flex container </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">

  </div>
  <div class="r_flex_expand_child">
    <article>an article blah blah blah an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf
      asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf
      asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article
      blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah
      blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah
      asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf
      asdf 1 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf
      asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf
      an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an
      article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an
      article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 1 an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 2 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah
      blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 3 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 4 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah
      asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 5 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 6 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf 7 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
      asdf asdf 8 an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf asdf asdf asdf an article blah blah blah asdfasdf
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="r_flex_fixed_child">
    this is the fixed footer child of the flex container asdfadsf
    <p> another line</p>
  </div>
</div>
```